# Wrong low/high/crit temperature levels reported by lm-sensors

Tags: linux, debian, supermicro, lm-sensors

Results reported by `lm_sensors` until now were OK, now all of a sudden I'm getting `0°C` for low/high/crit temperature levels:

```
% sensors
jc42-i2c-0-1a
Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 0580
temp1:        +26.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C)                  ALARM (HIGH, CRIT)
                       (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

jc42-i2c-0-18
Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 0580
temp1:        +24.8°C  (low  =  +0.0°C)                  ALARM (HIGH, CRIT)
                       (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

jc42-i2c-0-1b
Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 0580
temp1:        +26.8°C  (low  =  +0.0°C)                  ALARM (HIGH, CRIT)
                       (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

jc42-i2c-0-19
Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 0580
temp1:        +25.8°C  (low  =  +0.0°C)                  ALARM (HIGH, CRIT)
                       (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
```

Why has this happened and how can I fix that?

OS:

```
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:    9.6
Codename:   stretch
```

Motherboard is Supermicro:

```
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: X10SL7-F
```

`lm-sensors`:

```
ii  libsensors4:amd64                             1:3.4.0-4                                  amd64        library to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
ii  lm-sensors                                    1:3.4.0-4                                  amd64        utilities to read temperature/voltage/fan sensors
```